# Fancybox - image and iframe content in gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancy Box and Elevate Zoom together - I am trying to open both images and iframe content in to a gallery.

This works fine individually but when I click on the 'click to zoom' link for the images and scroll through the gallery, when it gets to the iframe it says 'content cannot be loaded'. However, if you click on the 360 spin icon it opens the iframe content in a lightbox.

My code is below - can anyone point me in the right direction to get this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
<link href="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/tangibles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />   
<script src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.elevatezoom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

</head>
<!--/End Head/-->


<body >

<!--/Start Container/-->
<div class="wrapper_inner"> 

<!--/Start Content Area/-->
<div id="content_area" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

    <!--/Start Product Spotlight Container/-->
        <div id="product_spotlight_container" class="tangibles">
            <div class="zoom" style="width:297px; height:208px;">
                <a href="#" rel="example_group">
                <img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="tangprodpagezoom" src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-large.jpg" width="300" title="test"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="img_zoom_text" class="zoom">
                <a href="#" rel="example_group">
                <span>Click to zoom</span> 
                </a>
            </div>                        

            <div id="gallery_01" style="width:300px; float:left;">
                <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery active" data-update="" data-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-large.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-xl.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-cross-sell.jpg" width="50" title="test1"/>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-other-large.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-key-other-xl.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/thumb2.jpg" width="50" title="test2"/>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="elevatezoom-gallery" data-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-large.jpg" data-zoom-image="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/heart-new-xl.jpg">
                    <img src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/thumb3.jpg" width="50" title="test3"/>
                </a>
                <a href="http://www.swiftspin360.com/buyagift/" class="fancybox.iframe" id="spin360" data-fancybox-href="http://www.swiftspin360.com/buyagift/" rel="example_group">
                    <img src="http://www.cjabeta.co.uk/test/images/spin_icon.jpg" width="50" title="360 view"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tangprodpagezoom").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', zoomWindowWidth:0, zoomWindowHeight:0, galleryActiveClass: "active"}); 
        $("#img_zoom_text").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', zoomWindowWidth:0, zoomWindowHeight:0, galleryActiveClass: "active"}); 
        $('#spin360').fancybox({'type':'iframe','width': 600, 'height': 400});
        $("#tangprodpagezoom, #img_zoom_text").bind("click", function(e) {  
          var ez =   $('#tangprodpagezoom').data('elevateZoom');
          ez.closeAll(); //NEW: This function force hides the lens, tint and window 
            $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
            $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'titleShow'         : 'true',
            'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
            'showNavArrows'     : 'true'
                });

          return false;
        }); 
        }); 

        </script>
        <!--/End Product Spotlight Container/--> 

</div>
</div>




</body>
<!--/End Body/-->
</html>
```

Comment: try `class="iframe"` instead of `class="fancybox.iframe"` ... why? you are using fancybox v1.3.4. BTW, since you are using v1.3.4 you don't need this `fancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js` because that is for v2.x

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/Pbbsj/1/ .

Comment: Thanks but neither seem to work - when the gallery opens up in a larger lightbox and I scroll through to the iframe it still says 'content cannot be loaded'.